# How can I use Android webview in system app

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want use a WebView in my app which has a system sign. But when I load the web page, it stopped at 10% progress.But if I removed `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system` it can load as normal. So how can I use WebView in this situation.

my android version is Android 12

I want the WebView work as well

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.